# Disable other div box with click, how to save clicked box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseleave

I have more boxes on the same page, with this code i can enable individually boxes, but how can i disable old box if i click on a new box?:

```
$('div.article').click(function(){
    var clickedbox = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + clickedbox + ' span.boxcontent').show();    
});
```

I have tried this to do also with jquery and with *.mouseleave*, but that's not good for mobile devices.

Comment: Like a radio control?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - yes, like radio buttons

Comment: @MirkoSimic are each of the radio buttons wrapped inside divs with class article?

Comment: here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/longweb/7zJvU/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide everything first & handle the one you have clicked later.

```
$('div.article').click(function(){
    var clickedbox = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.boxcontent').hide();
    $('#' + clickedbox + ' span.boxcontent').show();    
});
```

Comment: good.. glad to help, jsfiddle makes it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: In the future i will use always jsfiddle :)